# Google map multiple marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know this has been asked a lot of times over the net. But I still cant solve this, been a few days already but I still can't solve it. I am still new to this google map API thing and maybe there are some that I have mixed up or something.

Below is my current code:

```
var places = [
              ['Car Park', 1.301526,103.849379, 4],
              ['Bus Stop', 1.301132,103.850077, 3],
              ['MRT', 1.298515,103.845785, 2],
              ['Success Human Resource Center', 1.301486,103.849712, 1]
            ];

            var companyImage0 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/map-icon.png',
                new google.maps.Size(54,62),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(50,50)
            );

            var companyImage1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/MRT.png',
                new google.maps.Size(30,30),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(50,50)
            );

            var companyImage2 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/bus-stop.png',
                new google.maps.Size(30,33),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(50,50)
            );

            var companyImage3 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/car-park.png',
                new google.maps.Size(30,30),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(50,50)
            );

            var companyShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/logo_shadow.png',
                new google.maps.Size(54,62),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(65, 50)
            );

            /*var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(1.301486,103.849712);*/

            for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
            var place = places[i];
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(place[1],place[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                shadow: companyShadow,
                icon: companyImage[i],
                title: 'Singapore',
                zIndex: places[2][2]});
            }
```

Aside from that, I only want to display the infowindow when user click on SHRC marker, the Bus Stop and MRT will have nothing when the marker is clicked.

Appreciate any kind souls who can help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you didn't define companyMarker anywhere in the code - is it a typo or should it be marker ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, since you say nothing about the error you're receiving.  However, you have three errors in your code:

`CompanyMarker` hasn't been initialized, and you're using the wrong variable name and syntax for the z-index.  Remember that arrays are zero-based index, so

```
places[2] // will retrieve the SHRC row data
places[2][2] //will retrive the Z-index number from the SHRC row
```

So, try the following changes:

```
var places = [
  ['Bus Stop', 1.301132,103.850077, 3],
  ['MRT', 1.298515,103.845785, 2],
  ['SHRC', 1.301486,103.849712, 1]
];

//change marker to companyMarker
var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  shadow: companyShadow,
  icon: companyImage,
  title: 'Singapore',
  zIndex: places[2][2]}); //<- change from place[3], get the z-index number
}

google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,companyMarker);
});
```

Lastly, if you have other event handlers for the Bus Stop and MRT markers, then you need to add `infowindow.close(map, someMarkerName)` to the `companyMarker` listener to close the respective windows.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the help. Actually I wanted to display 3 markers on the map but only the SHRC have infowindows, the rest of the 2 markers is just markers without the infowindow. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Assuming that `companyMarker` is bound to SHRC, the click event handler you defined will work.  You don't have to bind an event to the other two markers if you don't want.

Comment: Hi Jason, I see. Thanks for the help, it worked! I have not tried the event handler though but managed to show the 3 markers. I have add in 1 more marker and would like to ask can the 4 markers be different image? I have edit my code above, please advise what should I do next. I have tried to add [i] after the companyimage but nothing is happening.

Comment: Hi Jason, is it able to do that?